# TFE cli Error updating workspace <WORKSPACE_NAME>

Tags: terraform, terraform-enterprise

I'm working on TFE through CLI, trying to update a workspace branch for configuration, the following command returned an error: **Error updating workspace**

```
tfe workspace update -name {workspace_name} -tfe-address {tfe_address} -vcs-id {repo_name} -vcs-branch {branch_name} -token {token}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if you have defined these variables or not? and don't forget the dollar `$` in front of the variables.

So the command should be changed to

```
tfe workspace update -name ${workspace_name} -tfe-address ${tfe_address} -vcs-id ${repo_name} -vcs-branch ${branch_name} -token ${token}
```

You can verify if these variables have proper value or not with below way:

```
echo ${workspace_name} 
echo ${tfe_address}
echo ${repo_name}
echo ${branch_name}
echo ${token}
```

Second, [tfe](https://github.com/hashicorp/tfe-cli/blob/master/bin/tfe) is for terraform enterprise, and written by shell script, could you run with `sh -x tfe ...`, what extra outputs you get, and can you paste the details in your question?